# Create FileAdmin Group to allow domain admins full file access on server 2008 r2

Tags: uac, windows-server-2008-r2

So, there used to be a very useful article explaining windows 2008 r2 uac and permissions here  http://blog.akinstech.com/understanding-windows-7-and-2008-r2-uac-and-permissions/

This explains why even though you are logged on as a domain admin you still can't do anything because of the two tokens yada yada.

I kick myself since I didn't make a copy of the article

But his method to allow domain admins to use files with full permissions was to create a local group called F_FileAdmin and then use icacls to grant that group full rights to the C:\ and then add domain admins to that group. I thought it was a pretty elegant approach.

So, anyone know the icacls syntax off hand to accomplish this? And or can pull up the article from some cache somewhere and or contact Mr. akinstech and ask him to put this very useful article back online :)

Answer (score 1):

A-Ha! I did save it. I realize I'm a year to late here, but maybe someone else can use it.

Create a group called F_FileAdmin and add the users you want to it.

```
icacls D:\ /grant "F_FileAdmin":(OI)(CI)F /T
```

This will add the “F_FileAdmin” group to the entire D: drive and propogate the permissions down to all subfolders and files, ensuring you have access.

Stick this batch file in your scripts directory such that it is in your path.  Now on any server, from an elevated command prompt, you can provision a folder by simply typing:

```
setfileadmin d:\SharedData
setfileadmin e:\
setfileadmin "f:\Accounting Files"
```

Or even use it remotely like this…

```
setfileadmin \\MyServer\d$\GroupData
```

Comment: Awesome, and double awesome